# Как сделать так чтобы авторизация и регистрация срабатывала на всех страницах?

Tags: php

Помогите разобраться с такой темой ,на сайт в шапку добавил модальное окно для авторизации и регистрации, но авторизация срабатывает только на страницах:

**мойсайт.ru/user/login
мойсайт.ru/user/register**

Как сделать чтоб она срабатывала на всех страницах сайта из модального окна?

Ссылка на сайт: ylino.ru (без модального окна)

буду благодарен за помощь

КОД МОЕГО МОДУЛЬНОГО ОКНА:

```
<?php
        /**
         * Авторизация
         * @var $this Users
         */
        ?>
        <div class="cd-user-modal"> <!-- this is the entire modal form, including the background -->
        <div class="cd-user-modal-container"> <!-- this is the container wrapper -->
            <ul class="cd-switcher">
                <li><a href="#signin">Авторизация</a></li>
                <li><a href="#signup">Регистрация</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="cd-login"> <!-- log in form -->
                <form id="j-u-login-form" action="" class="cd-form">
                <input type="hidden" name="back" value="<?= HTML::escape($back) ?>" />
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="j-u-login-email"><?= _t('users', 'Электронная почта') ?></label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="j-u-login-email" class="full-width has-padding has-border" placeholder="<?= _t('users', 'Введите ваш email') ?>" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Ошибка, укажите вашу почту!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="j-u-login-pass"><?= _t('users', 'Пароль') ?></label>
                        <input type="password" name="pass" id="j-u-login-pass" class="full-width has-padding has-border" placeholder="<?= _t('users', 'Введите ваш пароль') ?>">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Показать</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Ошибка, укажите ваш пароль!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember-me" autocomplete="on" checked>
                        <label for="remember-me"><?= _t('users', 'Запомните меня'); ?></label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <button type="submit" class="full-width j-submit"><?= _t('users', 'Войти на сайт') ?></button>
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="#0">Забыли пароль?</a></p>
                <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Закрыть</a>
            </div> <!-- cd-login -->

            <div id="cd-signup"> <!-- sign up form -->
                <form id="j-u-register-form" action="" class="cd-form">
                <input type="hidden" name="back" value="<?= HTML::escape($back) ?>" />
                    <!-- <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-username" for="signup-username">Имя полизователя</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="signup-username" type="text" placeholder="Придумайте имя">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
                    </p> -->

                    <? if($phone_on) { ?>
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-phone" for="j-u-register-phone signup-phone"><?= _t('users', 'Телефон') ?></label>
                        <div class="controls form-control-phone">
                            <?= $this->registerPhoneInput(array('id'=>'j-u-register-phone','name'=>'phone')) ?>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                    <? } ?>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="j-u-register-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="full-width has-padding has-border j-required" id="j-u-register-email" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?= _t('users', 'Введите ваш email') ?>" maxlength="100" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Ошибка, вы забыли указать вашу эл. почту!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="j-u-register-pass">Пароль</label>
                        <input type="password" name="pass" class="full-width has-padding has-border j-required" id="j-u-register-pass" autocomplete="off" placeholder="<?= _t('users', 'Придумайте пароль') ?>" maxlength="100">
                        <a href="#0" class="hide-password">Показать</a>
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Ошибка, вы забыли указать пароль!</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="j-u-register-agreement" autocomplete="on">
                        <label for="accept-terms"><?= _t('users', 'Я соглашаюсь с <a href="[link_agreement]" target="_blank">правилами использования сервиса.</a>', array('link_agreement'=>Users::url('agreement'))) ?></label>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <button class="full-width has-padding j-submit" type="submit"><?= _t('users', 'Создать профиль') ?></button>
                    </p>
                </form>

                <a href="#0" class="cd-close-form">Закрыть</a>
            </div> <!-- cd-signup -->

            <div id="cd-reset-password"> <!-- reset password form -->
                <p class="cd-form-message">Забыли пароль? Пожалуйста, введите Ваш адрес электронной почты. Вы получите ссылку для создания нового пароля.</p>

                <form class="cd-form">
                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="reset-email">E-mail</label>
                        <input class="full-width has-padding has-border" id="reset-email" type="email" placeholder="Укажите ваш адрес эл. почты">
                        <span class="cd-error-message">Ошибка, укажите эл.почту</span>
                    </p>

                    <p class="fieldset">
                        <button class="full-width has-padding" type="submit" value="Восстановить"></button>
                    </p>
                </form>

                <p class="cd-form-bottom-message"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Вернутся к авторизации</a></p>
            </div> <!-- cd-reset-password -->
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="cd-close-form">Закрыть</a>
        </div> <!-- cd-user-modal-container -->
    </div> <!-- cd-user-modal -->
```

код обработчика https://gist.github.com/baytalov/521e7b56c60dcd3da199d028b9b029cc

[ДЕМО МОДУЛЬНОГО ОКНА КОТОРЫЕ Я ВНЕДРИЛ](https://codyhouse.co/demo/login-signup-modal-window/index.html)

Comment: а что значит "авторизация срабатывает только на страницах"? Что должно происходить на других страницах?

Comment: авторизация проходит только на тек страницах которые я перечеслил, а на других нечего не происходит, а должно происходит на любых страницах

Answer (score 0):

У вас в модальном окне в action отсутствует путь до обработчика, поэтому данные из формы отправляются на ту страницу, на которой пользователь находится.

Comment: я правильно понял что мне нужно в action добавить такой путь action="/user/login" ?

Comment: да, попробуйте.

Comment: переходит на страницу мойсайт.ru/user/login и нечего не происходит, просто попадаю на страницу авторизации (оригинал)

Comment: Может вам код модели предоставить если нужно ?

Comment: Посмотрите логи, а именно передаются ли данные на обработчик. У вас используется Ajax, поэтому здесь нужно более детально разбираться. Предоставьте код обработчика.

Comment: посмотрите помоему это он ))) https://gist.github.com/baytalov/521e7b56c60dcd3da199d028b9b029cc

Comment: испугались кода ахаха ))